# Handling mergeMap observable on undefined value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using angular 6 and have a class to join my API tokens to every http request. When `getIdToken()` returns successfully everything will be ok, but if it returns unsuccessfully, my app will be stop.

How can i handle `mergeMap` function when `getToken` gets failed?

I am confused about handling mergeMap observable function.

This is my class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { of } from 'rxjs';


import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private token;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.userService.getToken().mergeMap(
            (token) => {
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });
                return next.handle(request);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And these are my getToken functions from userService class:

```
  public async getIdToken() {
    if (this.getCurrentUser() !== null) {
      try {
        const session = await this.getCurrentUserSession();
        return session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    } else {
      return Promise.reject('No Current User');
    }
  }

  public getToken(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.getIdToken());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a catch right before your `mergeMap` like this :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return this.userService.getToken()
        .catch(error => // manage your error here)
        .mergeMap(
            (token) => {
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', token) });
                return next.handle(request);
            }
        );
}
```